# "wasn't" vs "weren't"

Tags: subjunctives

According to Google Search, `"if it wasn't for you <verb>ing"` and `"if it weren't for you <verb>ing"` are both used.

What is the correct usage of `wasn't` or `weren't` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English the Past subjunctive mostly has the same form as the normal Past (indicative).
That's why Pt* (Past subjunctive) is only used with special indicators, after words as, for example, "if, as if/as though" + would in the main clause.
The only verb that has special forms for Pt* is *to be*:

Past was/were/was - were/were/were,
Pt*  were/were/were - were/were/were

But as Pt* has mostly the same form as normal Past, in colloquial speech the genuine subjunctive "you were*" is mostly replaced by "you was". This is a bit earth-bound and in more elevated style you still use the proper subjunctive "you were*".