# " ... as if the dog were its mother" - why "were" and not "was"?

Tags: past-tense

I passed a test and this question confuses me:

> The young chick, separated from its mother after hatching, followed the family dog around as if the dog *were its mother*

I chose "was its mother" as the correct answer, but it seems like the correct answer is "were".

The question is, why are we using "were" when we are referring to a singular form of a third person?

The following makes sense to me:

> ... As if you were its mother

But using "were" for the answer is like saying "He were", which doesn't make sense to me. It must be "You were" and "He was".

What's the reason for this?

**UPDATE:** I've read the answer links that are marked as duplicates of this question. I already know those answers. But they are talking about "You", while my question is why we are still using "Were" when both of the subjects are "Him/Her", not "You".

Comment: Strictly speaking, *were* is "correct" there because it's a *subjunctive* usage. But in practice native speakers often just use Simple Past, even though some pedants object to things like *If I was you I wouldn't do that.*

Comment: Related: [“wasn't” vs “weren't”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16902)

Comment: @sumelic: I think my link covers the whole issue so much better that I've closevoted *yours* against it as well! But there's also the possibility here of *as if the dog **had been** it's mother*, which might be a whole nother ball game.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But we are not talking about any "you" here. they are both absent, and both third person. I can understand when we say "as if YOU were" its mother, but not "as if HE were its mother". The post you marked as duplicate is considering a 2nd person too, which is not the case here.

Comment: @JackJohansson: In "If I were you," the subject of "were" is the first-person singular pronoun "I."

Comment: @sumelic So, in "if he were", the subject is "He". Yet still we use "were", while we should say "he was".

Comment: It is a special case. For the so-called "past subjunctive," the conjugation goes "I were/he were/she were/it were." As you know, these are not correct in other contexts.

Comment: @sumelic So it's like a bug in the language :D

Comment: Hi Jack, I have undeleted this question, because it is a well-written question, and I think it will help other learners find the other question. We are [discussing it on our meta site](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3511/) if you have questions or concerns about why I undeleted it.

Comment: @ColleenV Hi, Thank you. I thought because it's duplicate, it might not be useful anymore.